# JDeveloper 11.1.1.4 Error Issues (Potential lack of memory or Versioning Support Extension issue)

Tags: svn, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am having a constant issue with JDeveloper, where an error is produced on start-up saying it is unstable. The error can be seen below:

[image: start-up error]

The only way I have been able to prevent this error is by disabling the Versioning Support Extension (for SVN). Unfortunately, this has side-effects and I tend to get random errors as below, where functionality doesn't work:

[image: adding method binding error]

If I leave the extension turned then the application eventually crashes. It should be noted that this occurs when I'm trying to navigate a very large source base; if I create a new application then the first error isn't displayed on start-up. As a result this made me think it was a memory issue, but I tried increasing the memory via the JDeveloper config, and that did nothing to help.

Just to make it clear, I've downloaded and installed this version of JDeveloper on 4+ different environments and the same issue is encountered.

Updating to a newer version of JDeveloper is currently not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a problem with your Local SVN version on your machine, you might have SVN or Tortoise SVN version higher than JDeveloper can understand, that's why it's given you this error and that's why when you disable the SVN it starts.

Check [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/groundside/entry/using_jdeveloper_11_1_1) which I believe explains your problem

Comment: This sounds like it may be the problem as the one environment that doesn't have TortoiseSVN on it has no issues. I'll test it and then accept the answer if that's the case.